# Perform merge/insert on two spark dataframes with different schemas?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark dataframe df and df1 both with different schemas.

DF:-

```
val DF  = Seq(("1","acv","34","a","1"),("2","fbg","56","b","3"),("3","rty","78","c","5")).toDF("id","name","age","DBName","test")

+---+----+---+------+----+
| id|name|age|DBName|test|
+---+----+---+------+----+
|  1| acv| 34|     a|   1|
|  2| fbg| 56|     b|   3|
|  3| rty| 78|     c|   5|
+---+----+---+------+----+
```

DF1:-

```
val DF1= Seq(("1","gbj","67","a","5"),("2","gbj","67","a","7"),("2","jku","88","b","8"),("4","jku","88","b",7"),("5","uuu","12","c","9")).toDF("id","name","age","DBName","col1")
    
+---+----+---+------+----+
| id|name|age|DBName|col1|
+---+----+---+------+----+
|  1| gbj| 67|     a|   5|
|  2| gbj| 67|     a|   7|
|  2| jku| 88|     b|   8|
|  4| jku| 88|     b|   7|
|  5| uuu| 12|     c|   9|
+---+----+---+------+----+
```

I want to merge DF1 with DF based on value of id and DBName. So if my id and DBName already exists in DF then the record should be updated and if id and DBName doesn't exist then the new record should be added. So the resulting data frame should be like this:

```
    +---+----+---+------+----+----+
    | id|name|age|DBName|Test|col |
    +---+----+---+------+----+----+
    |  5| uuu| 12|     c|NULL|9   |
    |  2| jku| 88|     b|NULL|8   |
    |  4| jku| 88|     b|NULL|7   |
    |  1| gbj| 67|     a|NULL|5   |  
    |  3| rty| 78|     c|5   |NULL|
    |  2| gbj| 67|     a|NULL|7   |
    +---+----+---+------+----+----+
```

I have tried so far

```
val updatedDF = DF.as("a").join(DF1.as("b"), $"a.id" === $"b.id" &&  $"a.DBName" === $"b.DBName", "outer").select(DF.columns.map(c => coalesce($"b.$c", $"b.$c") as c): _*)
```

Error:-

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`b.test`' given input columns: [b.DBName, a.DBName, a.name, b.age, a.id, a.age, b.id, a.test, b.name];;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting non-existent columns, and also there is a typo in the `coalesce`. You can follow the example below to fix your issue:

```
val updatedDF = DF.as("a").join(
    DF1.as("b"), 
    $"a.id" === $"b.id" &&  $"a.DBName" === $"b.DBName", 
    "outer"
).select(
    DF.columns.dropRight(1).map(c => coalesce($"b.$c", $"a.$c") as c) 
    :+ col(DF.columns.last) 
    :+ col(DF1.columns.last)
    :_*
)

updatedDF.show
+---+----+---+------+----+----+
| id|name|age|DBName|test|col1|
+---+----+---+------+----+----+
|  5| uuu| 12|     c|null|   9|
|  2| jku| 88|     b|   3|   8|
|  4| jku| 88|     b|null|   7|
|  1| gbj| 67|     a|   1|   5|
|  3| rty| 78|     c|   5|null|
|  2| gbj| 67|     a|null|   7|
+---+----+---+------+----+----+
```

Comment: dont know why i am getting error:- Error : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'DBName' is ambiguous, could be: a.DBName, b.DBName.;

for the first time it ran successfully but getting error on second run. Can you help me out here. i am running the code in azure notebook.

Comment: I tested on your given data but could not reproduce this error...

Comment: Additional comment:- what if my new column position changed? will that code work? i am afraid to say that it wont work in said scenario. 


Thanks for time.

Comment: Additional comment:- what if my new column position changed? will that code work? i am afraid to say that it wont work in said scenario. 

**Scenario:-** 
DF column order :- id|name|age|test|DBName
DF1 column order :- id|name|age|col1|DBName|

code should work irrespective of new column position. this code will work only if one new column added to right, what if multiple new column found in dataframe 

Thanks for time.

Comment: If you have a new question, please click the [ask question] button to ask a new question, thanks @DeepakKumar